# R session abort when I use assignTaxonomy

Tags: r, session, abort

I have been having this problem for more than a week now and I am running out of time and patience.This problem occurs when I run my script on a Mac and when I run it on a PC (no difference of results from more RAM, it just aborts faster). When I try to run this line of my dataset, the session aborts.

```
  set.seed(119)
  tax_PR2 <- assignTaxonomy(seqtab, 
                      "~/Desktop/Documents/Bruts/aeDNA_data_shared/pr2_version_4.11.1_dada2.fasta",
                      multithread=TRUE)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem is? I verified my dataset (seqtab is currently considered by R as a large matrix of 3930724 elements of 20.2Mb), I verified the space I have on my computer, I have all the needed packages to run this line of code and I tried different sources of genome database for PR2 (PR2 version 4.11.1 or 4.12.0 etc...) and it always has the same result.

If you have any ideas I would appreciate them. I hope the information I gave is sufficient.

Packages installed:

```
   library(BiocManager)
   library(Rcpp)
   library(dada2)
   library(ff)
   library(ggplot)
   library(gridExtra)
   library(phyloseq)
   library(vegan)
```

Comment: It's always trickier to help without a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But have you try with another file? Do you still get the same issue when `multithread=FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by a bug that was introduced in 1.14, see the Github issue here for more information: https://github.com/benjjneb/dada2/issues/916

We've just identified the cause, and a fix should be out soon. For immediate use, the workaround is to turn off multithreading, or to revert to the previous release 1.12.